# Should I use Ionic only for web application?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular-material

We are building an enterprise grade app which will be serve only on browser (i.e. it is only a web application, not mobile app). Also it will be never converted in mobile app.

Can someone please share your recommendations/experiences, what would be more appropriate to use for development.

1.) Use Ionic framework

2.) Use Angular (https://angular.io) with Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/components/categories)

We are having expertise in Ionic (in mobile development), will there be any drawback if we go with Ionic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of advantages using Ionic, it adds a plenty of extras for you, BUT it makes your vendor package much more bigger and create a lot of useless dependencies for you and it could multiply the time of the whole development process because of the hacky solutions you should use sometimes (for example: implement scrolling on ios safari with advanced graphics => nightmare). Not to mention if you start the project with Ionic 3 you will use Angular (after Ionic 4 you could use Vue too.)

Angular is a great framework with a very active developer community. If you choose this option the vendor will be smaller, the app could be more stable and you can avoid the over-engineered solutions that you should use with Ionic.

In case of your team is experienced with Ionic, the Angular won't make much difference, just make your life easier.

We are mainly use Ionic framework for hybrid platform solutions and I do love this framework. **But only for web development, I really recommend Angular to you.**

Summary of disadvantages using Ionic on this project:

- Much more dependencies
- Bigger vendor
- Performance issues/memory leaks
- Plenty of boilerplates
- Not so elegant solutions
- The maintenance would be harder because of the breaking changes in the future.

Comment: Thanks so much @péter-váradi for the information, this will be indeed helpful for us.

Comment: I am facing a similar question. I want to be able to deploy my app as both mobile and standard web app. With Ionic 5, is it possible to deploy the final app as a traditional web app which will adjust the layout based on the browser sizes?